# Getting .mesh & .skeleton from Blender2Ogre export

Tags: blender, ogre

I have downloaded the add-on blender2ogre from this source :
http://code.google.com/p/blender2ogre/

And I have created a simple mesh, with walking animation (similar to the gingerbreadman tutorial). My question is, whenever I want to export the project, I can only see the `.scene` export format. There is no option whatsoever to export as `.mesh` and `.skeleton`. Also, how can I export the walking animation separately, in other words, if my project have couple more animation, how can i separate those during export?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this thread](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=71300) on the OGRE Forum will help you:

> [...] If you want to export more than one animation and give them names you need to convert your actions to nla strips:
>
> go to the nla-editor, choose an action and hit the 'snowflake'-button next to it. this will create an nla-strip based on the action. Note that blender will create a new nla-track for each new nla-strip. you can keep the strips in different tracks or move them into one and delete the others.
>
> The exporter will export every nla-strip as an animation and give the animation the strip's name. One thing to pay attention to is, that nla-strips that are overlapping on the time-line will influence each other when exporting. The newest version of the exporter has an option to disable this influence. [...]